# Is it possible to create an HTML page without the use of MySQL?

Tags: php, html, automation

From what I have so far, I have an HTML form using method POST for PHP. What I want to do is automatically create a page using the input that includes a stylesheet and things that aren't in the form. I know that it is possible to create an XML page like this, as I have, but can you make an HTML page? Here is what I have so far, including the creation of the XML page and is creating an HTML page much like creating an XML page?

HTML form:

```
<form action="insertpage.php" method="post" class="form">
        Noun<input name="form1" value="" type="text">
        Adjective<textarea name="form2"  cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

PHP creating XML file

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $xml->createElement ('root');
$xml->appendChild($root);

$form1 = $xml->createElement ('form1');
$vtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[form1]);
$form1->appendChild($vtext);
$root->appendChild ($form1);


$form2 = $xml->createElement ('form2');
$advtext = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[form2]);
$form2->appendChild($advtext);
$root->appendChild ($form2);
$xml ->save("words/$_POST[form1].xml"))) or die ("error creating file");
```

This works perfectly fine, except I cannot find a way to automatically create an HTML page with the user input. Is there any way to do this with PHP because that would be perfect too. By the way, I know this method is terribly unsafe, and I am working on creating some security like captcha. Also if you can't do this with PHP, is there any other programming language that can do this? Thank you

Comment: yes ... but what are you actully asking?

Comment: How to create an HTML page with User input automatically

Comment: this has nothing to do with the xml you posted then?

Comment: ok in future don't post irrelevant code, it confuses the likes of me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple idea to get you started.

HTML Template: template.html (Very much trimmed down)

```
<div>
    <p>[[name]]</p>
    <p>[[email]]</p>
</div>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="whatever.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address" />
    <button>Create Page</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="create_page" value="true" />
</form>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['create_page']))
{
    $template = file_get_contents('template.html');
    $template_vars = array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email']
    );
    foreach ($template_vars as $k => $v)
    {
        $template = str_replace("[[{$k}]]", $v, $template);
    }
    file_put_contents('newfilename.html', $template);
}
```

Hope that helps.

It's worth mentioning that this is open to malicious user input, you should sanitize all the post data, this is just a very quick example.

Comment: seems like over kill when you could just echo the variable, if you want to template it, use a 'real' templateing engine.

Comment: @Dagon, You could just echo the variable yes, but he's asking how to create and save a HTML page from user input, and this is just one of many ways to go about it.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Just use e.g. `<?php echo $_POST['form1'];... ?>` tags together with `<input>`.

Comment: To save to file, could combine this with output buffering.